# Using pipes within map() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm getting unexpected results when attempting to pipe inside map()

```
map(ls(), ~ . %>% get %>% dim)
```

returns the following message:

```
Functional sequence with the following components:

 1. get(.)
 2. dim(.)

Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions.
```

I don't really know how functions() would get me the result I want.

Is there a way to do it with pipes and map?

Without using pipes,

```
map(ls(), ~ get(dim(.)))
```

, the result is what I would expect.

Comment: I would go for `lapply(mget(ls()), dim)` (without pipes)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`. %>% get %>% dim` is already a function so just omit the `~`, i.e.

```
map(ls(), . %>% get %>% dim)
```

or:

```
ls() %>% map(. %>% get %>% dim)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

I don't really understand how that chain is a function if I start it with data though.

Comment: A magrittr pipe whose left hand side is dot defines a function.   See the paragraph **Using the dot-place holder as lhs** in `help("%>%", "magrittr")`